# How do I dynamically change constant assignment?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing an insert with a select:

```
my_object_id = 7
id_list = [1,2,4,5]

TEST_TEMPLATE = %Q{
        INSERT INTO tests
        (test_id, data_id, text, created_at, updated_at)
        select #{my_object_id}, data_id, text, created_at, updated_at 
        from tests where id in (#{id_list})
    }

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(TEST_TEMPLATE);
```

I get error that I cannot change the constant. How do I inject values into a string so I can use it in my insert/select statements?

How can this be solved in Ruby?

Comment: What line of code generates the error? I don't see anything wrong with what you wrote above.

Comment: Maybe this is legacy code and you can't help it, but you shouldn't be generating raw SQL from a template and executing it with ActiveRecord. The main point of ActiveRecord is to abstract SQL, providing benefits like automatic escaping to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to make it a constant.

```
my_object_id = 7
id_list = [1,2,4,5]

test_template = %Q{
        INSERT INTO tests
        (test_id, data_id, text, created_at, updated_at)
        select #{my_object_id}, data_id, text, created_at, updated_at 
        from tests where id in (#{id_list})
    }

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(test_template)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit of an explanation to @SergioTulentsev answer:

You should change the first letter of `TEST_TEMPLATE` to lowercase, because variables starting with uppercase letters are not actually variables, they are constants, so you shouldn't change them.

As @SergioTulentsev shows in his code, you should change every letter to lowercase to match the style-conventions used in Ruby.

Comment: Actually, you can change constants in Ruby. You just get a warning about it.

Comment: And it's considered bad style to do so, which is why we get the warning.

Comment: [The Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) is worth reading multiple times.

Comment: @theTinMan I'll second that!